# How to take video on a raspberry pi with a usb webcam

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, camera, picamera

Hello I have a usb webcam and am too broke for the picamera, is there anyway I can write a python program that can record video??

Answer (score 1):

A few ideas spring to mind...

1. Identify which webcam you have
2. Plug it in and see if you can see it with:

   `sudo lsusb`
3. Install `v4l-utils` and see if it is accessible:

   `sudo apt-get install v4l-utils`

   `v4l2-ctl --list-devices`
4. Install `ffmpeg` and try using it:

   `sudo apt install ffmpeg`

   `ffplay /dev/video0`

If this works, you can record with `ffmpeg` or use **OpenCV** `videocapture()` to grab and record frames.

Comment: wait how do i use ffmpeg, cause  installing opencv seems like a lot

Comment: The `ffplay` command I mentioned is part of `ffmpeg`. Try 1-4 above first and report back how it goes. You may not need OpenCV.

Comment: Something along these lines `ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 25 -video_size 640x480 -i /dev/video0 output.mkv`

Comment: ok, now if the code runs multiple times will it overwrite the output video or make multiple also thank you so much!!!

Comment: It will ask if you want the video overwritten and stop if you say no. If you always want to overwrite, use `ffmpeg -y ...`

Comment: so I am planning on triggering this from a python program to make a game cam sorta thing, how do i make it so it changes the name like output1 output2 everytime, is this possible

Comment: It is, but I think you might need to look at **Udemy** or some tutorials online somewhere to get some Python skills under your belt.

Comment: yes I am very new to this, I kinda jumped in headfirst sorry for putting the burden on you